# How to transpose rows into columns between two cells which starts with certain value?

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have an excel sheet which will have rows with certain geographic parameters. I would like to transpose all the rows between **File** and next **File** to the adjacent columns. Original sheet is like that of the one in Image - 1. I would like get it transposed like that of the one in Image - 2.

For One Row - One Column, i've used this code http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/79645-copying-alternate-rows-data-into-column.html and it works perfectly. But don't know how to do it for multiple rows - columns transpose

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a VBA solution

```
Sub TransposeData()

    Const FirstRow As Long = 1
    Const WorkSheetName As String = "Sheet4"
    Dim arData, v
    Dim List As Object
    Set List = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
    Dim NextRow As Long, x As Long

    With Worksheets(WorkSheetName)
        arData = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
        NextRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("B:B")) + 1

        For Each v In arData
            If InStr(v, "File:") And List.Count > 0 Then

                .Cells(NextRow, "B").Resize(1, List.Count) = List.ToArray
                List.Clear
                NextRow = NextRow + 1

            End If
            List.Add v
        Next
        If List.Count > 0 Then .Cells(NextRow, "B").Resize(1, List.Count) = List.ToArray
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Only the first column is getting transposed. That too, the position of rows are interchanged instead of in order

Comment: All the data is in the first column?

Comment: Thanks mate. Now the order is ok. But instead of row after row, the whole column has been transposed into single - long - row

Comment: You'll need to fix `InStr(v, "File:") `.  This is what triggers the code to start a new row.

Comment: I didn't notice the colon. Used exactly the same "File:" string and now it's working perfectly. Thank you very much. Desperately needed this for my work

Comment: I'm glad that we got it to work. Thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 0):

This works in Google Sheets.
As a sample I had 3 records, each record has 4 items so i had data from A1 to A12 representing my 3 records.
You want to create a column for example B that has numbers from 0 to whatever.

Then in cell C1 you can have something like 
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,$B1*4+1,1)

and in cell D1 you can have something like
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,$B1*4+2,1)

and in cell E1 you can have something like 
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,$B1*4+3,1)

and in cell F1 you can have something like 
=INDEX($A$1:$A$12,$B1*4+4,1)

The so I was finished with first row, then i just click and dragged to fill the rest of the rows, and because $B1 the 1 doesn't have a dollar sign, it automatically read the next row from $B2 and $B3 and grabbed the right data.

Comment: Getting #REF# error. Tried even with simple three records of 12 rows. But still the same